# Consuming WCF with parameters with ServiceClient

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service and I'm to trying to consume it like this

`ServiceReference.ServiceClient service = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient();
service.function("Parameter1", "Parameter2");`

But when I debug I see that both parameters are

`ServiceName.ObjectId`

And I can't do anything with that. I actually make

`Substring(0,5);`

and the result would be

`"Servi"`

What do I have to do to get the value of the parameter sent?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Edit: pasted original

This is the service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWordBook
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool WCFFunction(string parameter1, string parameter2);
}
```

This is the service implementation:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class WCFService : IWCFService
{
    public bool WCFFunction(string parameter1, string parameter2)
    {
        return BusinessRules.BusinessFunction(parameter1, parameter2);
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it from an ASP.NET WebForms application.

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference.WCFServiceClient service = new ServiceReference.WCFServiceClient();

    service.WCFFunction("string1", "string2");
}
```

Comment: Post the code with original parameters

Answer (score 0):

Is this the original code? If yes, you are implementing the wrong interface. Also, need some more to go by. The client call looks alright.